# How do I remove these brackets?

Tags: ruby, rspec

My code is giving me the result I want, but it is not passing the rspec. here is my code:

```
def tokens(tokens)
   tokenized = []
   syms = %w(* / - +)
     tokenized << tokens.split.map{|i| syms.include?(i) ? i.to_sym : i.to_i}
     tokenized
   end
```

here is the respec:

```
# extra credit
  it "tokenizes a string" do
    calculator.tokens("1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /").should ==
      [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
  end
```

now, my code actually does, because it is in an array, return

```
[1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
```

but when I run the respec it wont pass because it gets an extra set of brackets on it like so:
Failures:

```
1) RPNCalculator tokenizes a string                                                                                           
     Failure/Error: [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]                                                                             
       expected: [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]                                                                                
            got: [[1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]] (using ==)
```

I figure the rspec is using an .inspect like method that is adding the brackets (I don't know exactly how .should works). For all points and purposes my code seems correct. But it won't pass as is. What should I do to make it pass?

Comment: It is usually good practice to upvote an answer as well as accept it. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass your spec, you have to change in `tokens` method like this.

```
def tokens(tokens)
   syms = %w(* / - +)
   tokens.split.map{|i| syms.include?(i) ? i.to_sym : i.to_i}
end
```

Comment: AH yes! map changes an array in place! no need to push it into a new array...tuh! lol! thanks

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns an array. So when you do

```
tokenized << tokens.split.map{|i| syms.include?(i) ? i.to_sym : i.to_i}
```

You're appending an array to the `tokenized` array. So your rspec should be

```
it "tokenizes a string" do
   calculator.tokens("1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /").should ==
   [[1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]]
end
```

Comment: as a last resort I will change the rspec...but I am not sure I am supposed to (I have to submit these assignments). Is there another way to go about it? Turning it to a string does not work, obviously, and using the `each` method gives me this : `got: [["1", "2", "3", "*", "+", "4", "5", "-", "/"]] (using ==)` Yikes. Whats up with that?

Comment: @HolyMoly why do you want to append it in first place? Why don't you do it like stated in the other answer?

Comment: lol, it just wasn't 'clicking' what I was doing wrong. seems so obvious now! I got it fixed. thanks Amit!